# Create a VFP Chrome or FireFox Object

Tags: sql-server, firefox, google-chrome, visual-foxpro, ole-automation

We have a VFP application and need to open a specific site in Chrome or Firefox.  The site is optimized for either of those browsers.

We know how to `Createobject` for `InternetExplorer.Application` to open a browser inside our application.  This allows us to interract with the browser.  However, it works only with `IE`.

Does anyone know how to accomplish the same purpose using either `Chrome` or `Firefox`?

We have done this to open the default browser (which is `Chrome` or `Firefox`).

```
oShell = Createobject("wscript.shell")
oShell.Run(lcUrl)
```

The issue with this approach is that it just opens the browser and we cannot interact with it (e.g. pass values and read items on the page).

At a minimum, if we can open `Chrome` or `Firefox` and pass POST parameters without using a `querystring` that would be an acceptable start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome doesn't expose an OLE Automation interface so I think you are out of luck with CreateObject(). You might be able to send keystrokes to it somehow but it would be kludgey at best.